# When I put a file (.pdf) in a sharepoint folder, I want it to go in a folder automatically created with the same name as the file

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow, power-automate

We have a folder named "X". When I put a .pdf named "human" into "X", I want a folder to automatically be created named "human" and it contains "human"(.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Try as following:

[image]

[image]

Here is the result in my test for your reference:

[image]